# UITableView won't update while active

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an array of objects, and i use following code to get in in the tableview

```
[source addObjectsFromArray:[UDdelegate naturArray]];
    
[[self tableView]reloadData];
```

My application fetch some data on location change, and that data is the objects in my naturArray. source is the list's datasource.

My problem is that if my list view is active while it is fetching the data, the list isn't updated. If i go to the main menu and back into the listView the data appear.

Is there a way to get the list to update while its active ?

Thanks.

### Edit: Full code

```
VisListe.h:
@class UdINaturenAppDelegate;
@class POI;
@class webDetailView;

@interface VisListe :  UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, retain,readwrite) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *dataSourceArray;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UdINaturenAppDelegate *UDdelegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) POI *poi;

@property (strong, nonatomic) webDetailView *webView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tabel;

-(void)updateList;

-(NSString*)parseURL:(NSString*)url;
@end
```

VisListe.m:

```
@implementation VisListe
@synthesize dataSourceArray = source;
@synthesize UDdelegate;
@synthesize poi=_poi;
@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize tabel = _tabel;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Poi List", nil);
        
        UDdelegate = (UdINaturenAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        source = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        _webView = [[webDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"webDetailView" bundle:nil];
        [self updateList];
        
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}



#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
   
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    //[source addObjectsFromArray:[UDdelegate naturArray]];
    
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [self setTabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    
    self.dataSourceArray = nil; // this will release and set to nil
    source = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    NSLog(@"unload");
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    [self updateList];
    
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
   
    
    
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

// to determine specific row height for each cell, override this.

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([indexPath row] == 0) ? 60.0 : 60.0;
}

// to determine which UITableViewCell to be used on a given row.

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    //return [UDdelegate naturArray].count;
    return [source count];
}
//
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    _poi = [source objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [_poi title];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Afstand: %f m.", [_poi dist]];
  //[cell.imageView setImage:<#(UIImage *)#>];
    
    return cell;
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    _poi = [source objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",[_poi title]);
    
    NSString* u = [self parseURL:[_poi webUrl]];
    
        
    
    [_webView setIncUrl:u];
   
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:_webView animated:YES];
       
}

-(NSString*)parseURL:(NSString*)url{
 
    
    NSString* s = [url stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   
    return s;
    
}


-(void)updateList{
    
    [source removeAllObjects];
    
    [source addObjectsFromArray:[UDdelegate naturArray]];
    
    [_tabel reloadData];
        
}

-(UIImage*)setImgFromUrl:(NSString*)url{
    
    NSURL *newurl = [NSURL URLWithString: url];
    
    
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: newurl]];

    return image;
    
}
```

When the location is fetched the updateList method is called from the AppDelegate.m

Comment: Create an outlet for your table and reload it.Like this  [dataTableView reloadData]; You have to reload it in respective method where you want..

Comment: Just tried it.. Still the same problem :(

Comment: Post your full method code..So that i can help you to fine where is the mistake.

Comment: Where did you define `_tabel`?

Comment: Forgot to post... :) edited again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that it was just me who was a little impatient. the [_tabel reloadData] method is just a little "heavy" to call, so the list was in fact updated, but it just took a little while to update.